# Saving relationships using the Django Rest Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Quando eu tento salvar um novo aluno informa o erro

> NOT NULL constraint failed: student_student.teacher_id

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, related_name='teacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class TeacherSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ['name']

class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    teacher = TeacherSerializer()   

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['id','name','teacher']
    def create(self, validated_data):
        teacher_data = validated_data.pop('teacher')       
        student = Student.objects.create(**validated_data)
        student.teacher=teacher_data
        student.save()       
        return student

class TeacherViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Teacher.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeacherSerializer

class StudentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer

{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Pablo",
        "teacher": {
            "name": "Pedro"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola,
Primeiramente ,O problema possivelmente poder ser o banco de dados, faça novamente o comandos no shell:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

e depois e

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Veja se apareceu as alterações.

Segundo,o outro possivel erro, é que Voce criou uma `ForeignKey` por padrão e ela não pode ficar `Null`, você tem terá que confirgurar como `Null=True`, então:

```
teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher,null=True, blank=True, related_name='teacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Espero que tenha ajudadado.

Link de referencia : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733221/django-db-utils-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed-products-product-ima/46497052#46497052